# Facebook graph API: Getting user Profile object null

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get user's profile using Facebook Graph API. But sometimes I am getting Profile object value null in GraphRequest response, but there JSONObject and GraphResponse are fine. Here is the code how I am doing.

Dependencies in build.gradle for Facebook SDK:

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.16.0'
```

In Activity I am doing:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        facebookCallback();
}

@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.txt_login_facebook:
                if (CommonUtils.isNetworkConnected(LoginActivity.this)) {
                    LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_birthday", "email", "user_location"));
                } else {
                    CommonUtils.showNoInternetAlert(LoginActivity.this, null);
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

private AccessToken accessToken;
private CallbackManager callbackManager;

private void facebookCallback() {
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
                new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
                getUserDataThroughGraphAPI();
                Log.i("error", "success" + "");
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Log.e("Facebook-Login-Cancel", "Cancelled");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                Log.e("Facebook-Login-onError", exception.toString());
            }
        });
    }

/**
     * This method gives you data from Facebook through Graph API after successful login to Facebook.
     * Use {@link #getUserDataThroughGraphAPI()}
     *
     * @return Nothing.
     */
    private void getUserDataThroughGraphAPI() {
        try {
            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(accessToken, new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject jsonobject, GraphResponse response) {
                    Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
                    Log.e("Facebook json", jsonobject.toString());//Getting Correctly
                    Log.e("Facebook graph", response.toString());//Getting correctly
                    Log.e("Facebook profile", profile+"");//Getting Profile Object null sometimes
                }
            });
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,link,email,gender,birthday,location");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Any help will be appriciated :)